# Calculate time difference between entries in a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

I have csv file with the data formatted like this 
`date,time,event,user,net` .
I need to go through each line of this file, and if event == start, 
continue till it reach the line with event == end for the same user and net, 
then calculate the time difference between the two events. 
I have this code:

```
import csv
import datetime
import time

with open('dates.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_read:
        if row[2]=="start":
            n1=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], '%H:%M:%S')

            for row2 in csv_read:
                if (row2[2]=="End" and row[3]==row2[3] and row[4]==row2[4]):
                    n2=datetime.datetime.strptime(row2[1], '%H:%M:%S')

                    print row[2],row[1], row2[2], row2[1]

                    diff = n2 - n1
                    print "time difference = ", diff.seconds
                    break
```

But the problem with this code is that when it find a match "End" and calculate the time, it will start searching from the line after the with the match "End", ignoring the lines before it.
as an example

```
May,20,9:02:22,2010,start,user1,net-3
May,20,9:02:23,2010,start,user1,net-3
May,20,9:02:55,2010,start,user1,net-2
May,20,9:02:55,2010,End,user1,net-3
May,20,9:03:43,2010,End,user1,net-2
May,20,9:02:55,2010,End,user1,net-3
May,20,9:03:43,2010,End,user1,net-2
May,20,9:03:44,2010,start,user1,net-2
May,20,9:03:49,2010,End,user1,net-2
```

will only produce the following output:

```
Connect 9:02:22 Disconnect 9:02:55
time difference =  33
Connect 9:03:44 Disconnect 9:03:49
time difference =  5
```

So does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem, please?
Also is it possible to add the time difference as an extra column to the existing data?

thanks

I've updated the code, but now I'm facing a new problem, my file contains 35734 rows, but the output file contain only 350 rows, I'm confused as to why this happens, and I would appreciate any help, thanks
Updated Code:

```
l1=[]  ## empty list
l2=[]  ## empty list

csv_file=open('dates_read.csv', 'r+')
csv_wfile=open('dates_write.csv', 'w+')

csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file)
csv_read1 = csv_read
csv_write = csv.writer(csv_wfile)
for row in csv_read:
    s=csv_read.line_num
    if (row[4]=="start" and (s not in l1)):
        n1=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[2], '%H:%M:%S')

        l1.append(s)
        month = str(row[0])
        day = int(row[1])
        time = str(row[2])
        year = int(row[3])
        user = str(row[5])
        net = str(row[6])
        dwell_time = str(row[7])
        for row2 in csv_read1:
            e=csv_read1.line_num
            if (row2[4]=="End" and row[5]==row2[5] and row[6]==row2[6] and (csv_read1.line_num not in l2)and s<e):
                n2=datetime.datetime.strptime(row2[2], '%H:%M:%S')
                diff = n2 - n1
                dwell_time= diff
                print("time difference = ", diff.seconds,"\n")
                csv_write.writerow([month, day, time, year, user, net, dwell_time])
                l2.append(e)
                break
print (s) #prints 818
print (e) #prints 35734
```

Answer (score 4):

The only problem with your code is that you are traversing the lines for **END** keyword right after it encounters the first **START** . Instead it should traverse the line of the file from the beginning.
With that we also had to take into consideration that same line doesn't get traversed again. For that we can use a list, that can hold the line number of the line been traversed.

Instead of writing a new code i made changes to your code only.

```
>>> l=[]  ## empty list
>>> csv_file=open('dates.csv')
>>> csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file)
>>> for row in csv_read:
            if row[0].split()[4]=="start":
                n1=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0].split()[2], '%H:%M:%S')
                s=csv_read.line_num
                csv_file1=open('/Python34/Workspace/Stoverflow/dates.csv')
                csv_read1 = csv.reader(csv_file1)
                for row2 in csv_read1:
                    e=csv_read1.line_num
                    ## Inside if iam adding to more checks that verify that the same line is not traversed again and the END flag is always encountered after START flag
                    if (row2[0].split()[4]=="End" and row[0].split()[6]==row2[0].split()[6] and row[0].split()[5]==row2[0].split()[5] and (csv_read1.line_num not in l) and s<csv_read1.line_num):
                        n2=datetime.datetime.strptime(row2[0].split()[2], '%H:%M:%S')
                        print("Connect : ",row[0].split()[2]," Disconnect :",row2[0].split()[2])
                        diff = n2 - n1
                        print("time difference = ", diff.seconds,"\n")
                        l.append(csv_read1.line_num)
                        del csv_read1
                    break
            del csv_file1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but the code seems not to work, first when I use <pre> row[0].split()[] <code> , but after I used jst <pre> row[] <code> it worked but there is no output, after adding some print statements it seems that the  if statement in <pre> row2 <code> is not excuting <pre> S:  2
 
E: 1
 
S:  3
 
E: 1
 
S:  4
 
E: 1
 
S:  7
 
E: 1 <code>

Comment: I copied your data file in a txt file, later i modified it to .csv format. Hence i needed to use "split()" format code.
One more thing iam using python 3.4

May be you can replace "row[0].split()[2]" with "row[1]".

Comment: thanks, but I still have a problem, I updated my code above, right now it does not go to the end of file, it only write the first 350 lines out of 35734

Comment: Could you share the file with me?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use a map for this problem.

Define (user_id, net_id) as key and (start_status,start_time) as value, like below:

```
class UserNet:
   user_id = -1
   net_id = -1
   // Other Operation

class StartStatus:
   start_flag = False
   start_time = -1
   // Other Operation
```

When you read one line, first judge status string in that line is START or END.

If it's END, then use 
 read from that line to find in the new map structure, find start_time and minus to get your answer.

If it's START, then insert that value in the new map structure.

start_flag isn't necessary if you don't want error judgment, it's flag to represent duplicated start for the same , maybe you don't need that.